# Random combinations without duplicates in Python

Tags: python, random, combinations

Suppose you have an iterable `t` of size `n`. You want to draw `l` random combinations of `r` elements from `t`. You require that the `l` combinations are different. Until now my take is the following (inspired by the iter tools recipes):

```
def random_combinations(iterable,r,size):
 n=len(tuple(iterable))
 combinations=[None]*size
 
 f=mt.factorial                                            # Factorial function
 nCr=f(n)//(f(r)*f(n-r))                                   # nCr
 iteration_limit=10*nCr                      # Limit of iterations 10 times nCr
 
 repeated_combinations=0                     # Counter of repeated combinations
 i=0                                         # Storage index
 
 combinations[i]=tuple(sorted(rn.sample(xrange(n),r)))      # First combination
 i+=1                                                    # Advance the counting
 
 while i < size:                                  # Loop for subsequent samples
  indices=tuple(sorted(rn.sample(xrange(n),r)))
  test=[ combinations[j] for j in range(i) ]
  test.append(indices)
  test=len(list(set(test)))
  if test == i+1:                                           # Test of duplicity
   repeated_combinations=0
   combinations[i]=indices
   i+=1
  else:
   repeated_combinations+=1
  if repeated_combinations == iteration_limit:       # Test for iteration limit
   break
 return combinations
```

Is there another way more efficient to do this? I ask this because I will be drawing several combinations from iterables that are huge (over 100 elements).

---

After selecting the most helpful answer, I confirmed that the problem with that solution was the iteration to filter the combinations that are not selected. However, this inspired me to look for a faster way to filter them. I end up using sets in the following way

```
import itertools as it
import math as mt
import random as rn

def random_combinations(iterable,r,l):
 """
 Calculates random combinations from an iterable and returns a light-weight
 iterator.
 
 Parameters
 ----------
 
 iterable : sequence, list, iterator or ndarray
     Iterable from which draw the combinations.
 r : int
     Size of the combinations.
 l : int
     Number of drawn combinations.
 
 Returns
 -------
 
 combinations : iterator or tuples
     Random combinations of the elements of the iterable. Iterator object.
 
 """
 pool=tuple(iterable)
 n=len(pool)
 
 n_combinations=nCr(n,r)                                                  # nCr
 if l > n_combinations:              # Constrain l to be lesser or equal to nCr
  l=n_combinations
 
 combinations=set()           # Set storage that discards repeated combinations
 while len(combinations) < l:
  combinations.add(tuple(sorted(rn.sample(zrange(n),r))))
 
 def filtro(combi):       # Index combinations to actual values of the iterable
  return tuple(pool[index] for index in combi)
 
 combinations=it.imap(filtro,combinations)              # Light-weight iterator
 
 return combinations
```

The set automatically takes care of repeated combinations.

Comment: Have you seen the `itertools` module with the `combinations` function?

Comment: `combinations` function was not the function that I wanted in principle, but now there is one answer that uses it in a way I did not think before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do select `l` random indices in the *C(n,r)* sequence and return the combinations corresponding to these selected random indices.

```py
import itertools
import random
import math

def random_combinations(iterable, r, l):
    copy1, copy2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
    num_combos = math.comb(sum(1 for _ in copy1), r)
    rand_indices = set(random.sample(range(num_combos), l))
    combos = itertools.combinations(copy2, r)
    selected_combos = (x[1] for x in  enumerate(combos) if x[0] in rand_indices)
    return list(itertools.islice(selected_combos, l))
```

To avoid iterating thru the combinations, we need a mechanism to skip over combinations.  I am not sure such a mechanism exists in Python's standard library.

Comment: For iteration do you mean the last step or the application of the `filter` in the last step?

Comment: I meant the iteration while filtering.  As for not processing the combinations after `l` have been extracted, you can use `itertools.islice` as in the edited response.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that your answer was more or less what I was looking for.

Comment: As you pointed, the weak point of this algorithm is the need to iterate through the combinations. Indeed it was slow and for my application it was taking ages only in the iteration. But I discovered another solution to the problem that became more efficient even. However, your solution inspired my solution. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it helped.  Depending on how close `l` is related to `C(n,r)`, I'd choose the above solution (when `l` is close to `C(n,r)`) or select unique randomly constructed combinations (when `l` is not close to `C(n,r)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than generating all the combinations, then choosing one of them (which will grow much much faster than `n`), instead do the following:

- Create an empty hash table or set.
- Choose a sample of `r` items in order (an implementation in pseudocode is below).
- Check whether the sample is already present (e.g., as a key in the hash table or a value in the set).  If not, store that sample (e.g., as a key in the hash table or a value in the set).
- Continue until `l` samples were stored this way.

The [pseudocode](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1190459/Random-Number-Generation-and-Sampling-Methods#Pseudocode_for_Random_Sampling) referred to is below.  See also L. Devroye's *Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation*, p. 620.

```
METHOD RandomRItemsInOrder(t, r)
  n = size(t)
  // Special case if r is 1
  if r==1: return [t[RNDINTEXC(n)]]
  i = 0
  kk = r
  ret = NewList()
  while i < n and size(ret) < r
    u = RNDINTEXC(n - i)
    if u <= kk
      AddItem(ret, t[i])
      kk = kk - 1
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
  return ret
END METHOD
```

Instead of the pseudocode above, you can also generate a random sample via reservoir sampling, but then it won't be trivial to maintain a canonical order for the sample.

Comment: My first take follows closely your pseudocode. Thank you so much for the try!